# Label in two rows

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have a label in 2 lines in my app but the last word in the first line breaks in two rows. For example if last word is 'home' I have h in the first line and ome in the second.
How can I fix that?

**UPDATE**:

Put over IB and in code word wrap but without success.

[image]

Code part:

```
...
cell.leftArticleTitleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

        [cell.leftArticleTitleLabel setLineBreakMode:TRUE];
        cell.leftArticleTitleView.frame = CGRectMake(cell.leftArticleTitleView.frame.origin.x, 40, 159, 40);
        cell.leftArticleTitleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(cell.leftArticleTitleLabel.frame.origin.x, cell.leftArticleTitleLabel.frame.origin.y, 149, 40);
...
```

**UPDATE 2**: Solved

I should put "setLineBreakMode:TRUE" first :-)

```
...
[cell.leftArticleTitleLabel setLineBreakMode:TRUE];
cell.leftArticleTitleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
cell.leftArticleTitleView.frame = CGRectMake(cell.leftArticleTitleView.frame.origin.x, 40, 159, 40);
cell.leftArticleTitleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(cell.leftArticleTitleLabel.frame.origin.x, cell.leftArticleTitleLabel.frame.origin.y, 149, 40);
 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the line break mode of the label to word wrapping.

graphically:

[image]

in code:

```
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

Comment: put both but with no success. Please take a look at my updated question.